# How can I correctly flag the end of the first sequence of a group?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is an example of the the type of dataframe that I'm using and the desired column output.

```
reprEx <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
             stage1 = c("open","open","open","approved","approved","open","declined","open","open","open","declined","open","approved","declined"))

Desireddf <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
             stage1 = c("open","open","open","approved","approved","open","declined","open","open","open","declined","open","approved","declined"),
             desiredResult = c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1))
```

I am trying to use dplyr to correctly flag whenever a stage changes within a grouped id. The approved and declined flags are easy because I only have to flag the first case of a declined or approved appearing with:

```
    reprExWrong <- reprEx %>% group_by(id,stage1) %>%
  mutate(desiredResult = ifelse(stage1 == last(stage1) & stage1 == "open",1,
                                ifelse(stage1 == first(stage1) & stage1 %in% c("approved","declined"),1,0)
                                )
  )
```

The issue is with the open stage. I only want to apply a flag for when the first sequences of opens ends within a group of id's. With the code that I have now it is choosing the last open within the group, even if it wasn't part of the first sequence of opens. for example:

```
reprExWrong <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
             stage1 = c("open","open","open","approved","approved","open","declined","open","open","open","declined","open","approved","declined"),
             notdesiredResult = c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1))
```

In this case, within id1 I would need the flag to show up where the sequence reaches the last open before approved appears, and not in the open after approved appears. I only need the flag in the row of the last occurrence of open if that succession of opens is the first succession within the id. Sorry for any confusion, I would be happy to further elaborate. This is just to correctly identify stage transitions for recording purposes

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: the expected output is within the first dataframe called reprEx, the column desiredResult is the output that I'd like to achieve.

Comment: You have typos in your code. Is it `reprEx` or `reprex`? `stage1` or `stage`? You say *"apply to each different id"* and then say *"3 ids and 3 groups"*, though it isn't stated that perhaps "stage1" (or "stage") is really a group. Having code in the question is good, but if it is riddled with typos like this, it's hard to not suspect that problems are due to typos, not logic or flow.

Comment: fixed typos, the issue wasn't that, was just trying to create a reproducible example, albeit sloppily.

Comment: I'd say `stage1 = last(stage1)` is still a typo, it should be `==`

Comment: Also, `stage1 %in% "open"` is confusing, make it `stage1 == "open"` if you are comparing to a single value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely there's something less convoluted, but this would likely work:

```
library(dplyr)

reprEx %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(idx = cumsum(stage1 != lag(stage1, default = first(stage1))),
         desiredResult = case_when(
           idx != lag(idx, default = first(idx)) & stage1 != 'open' ~ 1,
           lead(idx, default = last(idx)) != idx & stage1 == 'open' & idx == min(idx[stage1 == 'open']) ~ 1,
           TRUE ~ 0
         ),
         idx = NULL
  )
```

Output:

```
   id   stage1 desiredResult
1   1     open             0
2   1     open             0
3   1     open             1
4   1 approved             1
5   1 approved             0
6   1     open             0
7   1 declined             1
8   2     open             0
9   2     open             0
10  2     open             1
11  2 declined             1
12  3     open             1
13  3 approved             1
14  3 declined             1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
reprEx %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(lastopen=cumsum(lead(stage1!="open"))==1)
```

What this does is check for the first time stage1 is NOT "open" within an id group, and sets the line before that as TRUE. Result:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
      id stage1   lastopen
   <dbl> <fct>    <lgl>   
 1     1 open     FALSE   
 2     1 open     FALSE   
 3     1 open     TRUE    
 4     1 approved FALSE   
 5     1 approved FALSE   
 6     1 open     FALSE   
 7     1 declined NA      
 8     2 open     FALSE   
 9     2 open     FALSE   
10     2 open     TRUE    
11     2 declined NA      
12     3 open     TRUE    
13     3 approved FALSE   
14     3 declined NA
```

If the NAs are a problem, you can also add:

```
%>% mutate(lastopen=ifelse(is.na(lastopen),FALSE,lastopen))

# A tibble: 14 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
      id stage1   lastopen
   <dbl> <fct>    <lgl>   
 1     1 open     FALSE   
 2     1 open     FALSE   
 3     1 open     TRUE    
 4     1 approved FALSE   
 5     1 approved FALSE   
 6     1 open     FALSE   
 7     1 declined FALSE   
 8     2 open     FALSE   
 9     2 open     FALSE   
10     2 open     TRUE    
11     2 declined FALSE   
12     3 open     TRUE    
13     3 approved FALSE   
14     3 declined FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
reprEx %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(result = stage1 != lag(stage1), 
         result = ifelse(is.na(result), 0, result))
```